# Why db.session.remove() must be called?

Tags: python, session, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm following a tutorial to learn flask web developing, and here is its unit testing file:

```
import unittest
from flask import current_app
from app import create_app, db

class BasicsTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app('testing')
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_foo(self):
        pass
```

Also, I've found these sentences in [SQLAlchemy document](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#using-thread-local-scope-with-web-applications):

> Using the above flow, the process of integrating the `Session` with
>   the web application has exactly two requirements:
>
> - ......
> - Ensure that `scoped_session.remove()` is called when the web request ends, usually by integrating with the web framework’s event system to
>     establish an “on request end” event.

My question is: Why do I need to call `db.session.remove()`?

I think as long as `db.session.commit()` is not invoked, the database won't be modified. Also, when I comment out this line, the application will still be able to pass the unit test.

I've consulted the documents of both Flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy, but the former doesn't even mention `db.session.remove()`, while the latter is too abstract for me to understand.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah, but I think a session would be automatically removed when a request comes to an end.

Comment: @sunqingyao, that was basically I was trying to say, it the context of the code in your question I don't see any use for it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I've updated the question: It's not only the code, but also the document that confused me.

Comment: I imagine releasing the db connection back into the  pool is quite important and that is what the docs are saying.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Using the above flow, the process of integrating the `Session` with the web application has exactly two requirements:
>
> - ......
> - Ensure that `scoped_session.remove()` is called when the web request ends, usually by integrating with the web framework’s event system to establish an “on request end” event.

In **SQLAlchemy**, above action is mentioned because sessions in web application should be **scoped**, meaning that each request handler creates and destroys its own session.

This is necessary because web servers can be multi-threaded, so multiple requests might be served at the same time, each working with a different database session.

This scenario is beautifully handled by **Flask-SQLAlchemy**, it creates a fresh or new scoped session for each request. If you dig further it you will find out [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L819), it also installs a hook on `app.teardown_appcontext` (for Flask >=0.9), `app.teardown_request` (for Flask 0.7-0.8), `app.after_request` (for Flask <0.7) and here is where it calls `db.session.remove()`.

The *testing* environment does not fully replicate the environment of a real request because it does not push/pop the application context. Because of that the session is never removed at the end of the request.

As a side note, keep in mind that functions registered with `before_request` and `after_request` are also not called when you call `client.get()`.

You can force an application context automatically push and pop with a small change to your test instead of manually push in `setUp()` and pop in `tearDown()`:

```
def test_foo(self):
  with app.app_context():
      client = app.test_client()
      # do testing here for your endpoints
```

with this change the test passes without manually writing `db.session.remove()`.

The documentation for Flask-Testing seems to be wrong or more likely outdated. Maybe things worked like they describe at some point, but that isn't accurate for current Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy versions.

I hope this helps!

Comment: It's very helpful, and I love your `with app.app_context():` approach!

Comment: Hello, sir. I just reviewed this answer, but now I can't understand why you said _The testing environment does not fully replicate the environment of a real request because it does not push/pop the application context._ What's the difference between (i) manually pushing in `setUp()` and poping in `tearDown()`, and (ii) `with app.app_context():`?

Comment: my tests seem to indicate that `after_request` and `before_request` do get called during `client.get()`. However, it's true that triggering `client.get()` while within an `AppContext` the way you did will result in `RequestContext` not pushing an `AppContext` of its own (which is incidentally why there's no `AppContext` teardown and no triggering of the registered `teardown_appcontext` handlers). The doc does mention that `app.test_request_context()` does not trigger `before_request` and `after_request`.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't understand why `db.session.remove()` is necessary until I inspected the whole project:

This is because in `config.py`, `SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN` is set to `True`. As a result, changes made to `db.session` would be auto-commited if `db.session` isn't destroyed.